# Symfony2, custom ajax requests and CSRF

Tags: forms, security, symfony

I'm doing a website that uses a lot of Ajax requests and custom forms (hear: custom jQuery-forged POST requests with fields, or simple GET requests).
I know that Ajax and Symfony forms aren't incompatible (because the server doesn't see any difference), but that's not the question.

I'm very worried on CSRF attacks because my POST requests are not using the Symfony's official way to build and check forms, so I have no automatic CSRF protection.

**I have two questions:**

- Can I consider my POST requests as safe? The majority of CSRF attacks are done via `img` tags that points on the sensible endpoint. It is not possible to forge POST requests via images. Is the only way to do this is JavaScript injection? If I use Twig (safe user content including, thanks to HTML escaping), I will probably not have user-injected JS in the middle of my pages. So, am I out of danger?
- In any case, I have few GET sensible endpoints, too. I have to protect them. What is the most easy way to protect the associated actions? Append the links (GET parameter) with a token generated by the `form.csrf_provider` service, then verified at the entry of each involved action?

Comment: Why a downvote? Perhaps my question is silly, but it don't answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for CSRF and read more about it.

This type of attack can be used not only in `<img>` tags (actually I didn't think before that it can be used with `<img>`).

Attacker can create a form that will send post-request to your server and user will not know about that (if he will not see source of the page).

Comment: Yes, the `img` was just an example. Of course it works with all tags that can contain an URL automatically loaded by the browser. But this is only a GET request, and it is not recommended/standard to modify/delete informations on a GET request, that's why I will change my sensible GET requests to other methods.
Thanks for warning me about an external form!! A referer check is not sufficient... What do you recommend ? The tokens I was talking about?

Comment: CSRF-tokens are exist exactly for these purposes.

Comment: But what if the hacker GETs a page from the official site, parse the page, find the token and injects it into his proper form? (If this question seems stupid, sorry, maybe I've not yet understood how exactly the tokens are working).

Comment: Again, you need learn more about CSRF. Tokens live in the sessions.

Comment: Juste done some experiments, I saw that the hacker's external site can't load the official form (and parse the DOM to find the token) via ajax, thanks to CORS control. And even if CORS are enabled, the token is different on the aspirated site. If I send the form, Symfony rejects it. I think I begin to understand how CSRF tokens are working. I think I have all the answers I needed. Thanks!